# Power BI how to display latest value of a column based on date slicer and filter?

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax, measure

I have a Power BI table looks like this:

| Cat | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2.0 | 03/21/2021 |
| peach | 3.0 | 03/22/2021 |
| apple | 1.8 | 03/18/2021 |
| apple | 2.0 | 03/19/2021 |
| peach | 3.1 | 03/20/2021 |
| apple | 1.7 | 03/17/2021 |

I want to use a date slicer and Cat filter to choose the latest price for Apple and display in a tile:

Date Slicer: 03/12/2021 - 03/21/2021
Filter: check 'apple'

Tile display:  2.0

I tried

```
price_LastValue := CALCULATE(SUM(fruit[Price]), LASTDATE(fruit[Date]))
```

but the result is BLANK. Any thoughts?

Comment: I couldn't replicate your error, Is the selection of date meant to be outside the range of the selected `CAT`?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem either. There is something else in your Power BI model that affects your results but you have not included in the question. Could you post your data model diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
price_LastValue = 
VAR _tbl = ALLSELECTED(Table1)
VAR _max_date = MAXX(_tbl, [Date])
RETURN MINX(FILTER(_tbl, [Date] = _max_date), [Price])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what is 
VAR _tbl = ALLSELECTED(Table1) for?

Comment: It puts only filtered rows (both filtered by filter and by slider) into a `_tbl` variable. Later that variable is referenced 2 times